# What is the correct way to scope spring-batch components in an annotation driven configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am building a an application around spring MVC that incorporates spring-batch, that dynamically manages the batch processes in a manner similar to what spring-batch-admin does.  I am trying to use the spring-batch-admin as a foundation to understand what is happening, translating the context initializations into annotation driven configurations.

While the application is using annotation driven configuration as much as possible, the spring-batch jobs are externalized as XML files.

On startup, the AppInitializer fails after the ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean has been properly initialized, when it tries the refresh the context.  I know that the bean has been correctly initialized because it attempts to load one of the jobs, and can't find step-scoped beans.  (The process is not supposed to load and execute the job, it is only supposed to be able to find them at this point).

The jobs themselves work correctly under spring-batch-admin, so there is no issue with the jobs.

I am certain that I have simply misunderstood the contexts of the different pieces, and a resolution depends on getting the pieces into the right contexts.  Can anyone point out what I missed?

**Environment:**

```
Java 1.8
Spring 4.1.6
Spring-batch 3.0.2
Pivotal TC Developer Edition v3.0
```

Thanks in advance

Log excerpt:

```
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@425cccc3: defining beans [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope#0,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope#0,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,batch_state_transition_comparator,step0002-fetch,step0003-archive-purge,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean#0,archive-purge-mt]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@51ae827
WARN  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step0002-fetch': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sourceSelectionReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sourceSelectionReader' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sourceSelectionReader' is defined
    at 
...
```

sourceSelectionReader Bean

```
@Component("sourceSelectionReader")
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
public class SourceSelectionReaderImpl implements ItemReader<TreeModel>,
        ApplicationContextAware, StepExecutionListener, SourceSelectionReader {
```

AppInitializer:

```
    public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(MyConfig.class);
    rootContext.refresh();

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root appcontext
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    container.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");


    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext jobExecutionContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    jobExecutionContext.setParent(rootContext);
    jobExecutionContext.register(ExecutionContextConfig.class);
    jobExecutionContext.refresh();


    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    mvcContext.register(ViewConfig.class);
    mvcContext.setServletContext(container);

... (snip) ...          
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using the wrong paradigm here.  With a deeper look, I found that the JobRegistry component I was trying to use was meant load and execute directly from the classpath.

I have refactored using the DefaultBatchConfigurer, and moved on to the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `@Scope(value="step", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` or its shortcut `@StepScope`.

Comment: I tried that ... when I add StepScope, the Configurer no longer has access to the ApplicationContext, so application scoped beans (such as the configuration properties service or the datasource) are not available.

I don't want to execute the jobs at this point, simply to know that they exist

{
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'step'
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
}

Answer (score 0):

PICNIC error: I was using the wrong paradigm.  With a deeper look, I found that the JobRegistry component I was trying to use was meant load and execute directly from the classpath. I have refactored using the DefaultBatchConfigurer, and moved on to the next problem.